# How to do aggregation based on amount and currency in SQL Teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata, aggregation

I have table in SQL Teradata like below:

```
client|currency|amount
------|--------|-----
1233  |CZK     |300
1233  |CZK     |100
4577  |EUR     |200
1233  |EUR     |500
```

And I would like to calculate total amount and avg amount for each client in each currency and number of transactions using each currency for clients.

So using above table I need to have result like below:

```
client|avg_CZK |sum_CZK | avg_EUR | sum_EUR|number_CZ|number_EUR|
------|--------|--------|---------|--------|---------|----------
1233  |200     |400     | 500     |500     |2        |1
4577  |0       |0       |200      |200     |0        |1
```

How can I do that in SQL Teradata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select client,
       avg(case when currency = 'CZK' then amount end) as avg_czk,
       sum(case when currency = 'CZK' then amount end) as sum_czk,
       avg(case when currency = 'EUR' then amount end) as avg_eur,
       sum(case when currency = 'EUR' then amount end) as sum_eur,
       sum(case when currency = 'CZK' then 1 else 0 end) as num_czk,
       sum(case when currency = 'EUR' then 1 else 0 end) as num_eur
from t
group by client;
```

Comment: Great, but as I think in num_czk and num_eur it should be sum() instead of avg, right ?